# How do I permanently keep a network share in my Finder favorites?

Tags: macos, finder, smb

I added one of my network shares to my favorites. Whenever I lose connection to that share it gets removed from my favorites. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392029/how-can-i-place-a-shortcut-to-a-network-folder-in-my-sidebar/392031#392031

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep a Mac connected to a network drive, even after restarting, the easiest way to do this is to follow two major steps:

**First Mounting the Windows Share**

When you are in Finder you can click Go and Connect to Server or you can type Command + K to get to the same menu.

In Server Address you will need to put the location of your Windows share with this format smb://server/share where the server is the name or IP address of your Windows machine and share is going to be the folder or drive you to want to mount.

If your Windows share requires authentication it will ask you for that info here.

Now if you have Connected Servers showing on your desktop, it will show up on your desktop and in Finder.

**And last, Making the Share Mount at Login**

Follow the next step.

1. Hit the Apple menu, then System Preferences > Users & Groups
2. From here, select Login Items and click + to add a new item
3. Find your network drive and click Add, then close the window

[image]

**In another hand, you can try this too**

If it has an IP#, supports AFP and user authentication... maybe try this AppleScript as a start ( Create this with Script Editor ). Replace username, password, and IP with your info:

```
try

  mount volume "afp://username:password@ip_address/sharename"

end try
```

Save the script as an application

```
  File -> Save As -> File Format -> Application
```

Then go to

**Sys Prefs** -> **Accounts** -> **Login Items**

and add that application to your login items as shared on the first solution with the screenshot.

Comment: My issue was more that finder would remove the share's entry from my favorites if it was ever disconnected

Comment: I believe this really could be a macOS problem (bug?). My finder (Catalina 10.15.7) complains upon disconnect and asks to ignore or remove the share. Choosing to ignore will keep the sahre entry but only for a while. My expectation is that it would stay there until manual removal or reboot.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP asked about keeping the share in the Finder's Favorites.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an entry to Finder's favorites, that will automatically remount the share on click if it was disconnected.

Connect to the CIFS/SMB share you want to add to your favorite, then go there in Finder. Make sure you have the Path bar visible. If not, it's through
**View** > **Show Path Bar**.

Once there, you'll see the drive symbol as the first item in the Path Bar. Drag that into your favorites.

After this, you can eject or have the share disappear when it times out, but the favorite icon will stay behind, and clicking it will remount it.